# USB devices and NIC not detected when hotplugging Thunderbolt 3 (Intel Icelake / Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: usb, 19.10, thunderbolt

I bought a brand new Acer Swift 5 notebook: [SF514-54GT](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NX.HHVEK.001). This uses the new Intel 10th Gen i7-1065G7 chip accompained with an NVIDIA MX250 GPU. Pretty damn powerful.

When trying to hotplug a HP Thunderbolt 3 G2 Docking station, it properly detects the external screens (DP) and authorizes the dock:

```
root@qdrop-swift5:/home/qdrop# boltctl list
 ● HP Thunderbolt Dock G2
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          Thunderbolt Dock G2
   ├─ vendor:        HP
   ├─ uuid:          00e2202d-3182-f000-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     60201c9e-0ea8-8680-ffff-ffffffffffff
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Di 28 Jan 2020 19:45:59 UTC
   ├─ connected:     Di 28 Jan 2020 19:45:59 UTC
   └─ stored:        Di 28 Jan 2020 19:31:17 UTC
      ├─ policy:     iommu
      └─ key:        no
```

Yet, the USB devices and NIC are not recognized at all. When connecting the dock before booting, everything works as expected.

```
journalctl -u bolt

-- Reboot --
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 systemd[1]: Starting Thunderbolt system service...
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: bolt 0.8 starting up.
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: store: located at: /var/lib/boltd
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: config: loading user config
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: config: user config loaded successfully
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: config: auth mode set to 'disabled'
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: bouncer: initializing polkit
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: udev: initializing udev
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: store: loading domains
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [901fdff4-0845-domain?                    ] store: loading domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: journal: opened for '901fdff4-0845'; size: 0 bytes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [901fdff4-0845-domain?                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [b0487488-6ef6-domain?                    ] store: loading domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: journal: opened for 'b0487488-6ef6'; size: 0 bytes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [b0487488-6ef6-domain?                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [1050819f-020c-domain?                    ] store: loading domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: journal: opened for '1050819f-020c'; size: 0 bytes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [1050819f-020c-domain?                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [70a70644-67b0-domain?                    ] store: loading domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: journal: opened for '70a70644-67b0'; size: 0 bytes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [70a70644-67b0-domain?                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: store: loading devices
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [00e2202d-3182                            ] store: loading device
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: power: state located at: /run/boltd/power
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: power: force power support: yes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: udev: found 1 domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: udev: enumerating devices
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [60201c9e-0ea8-domain0                    ] newly connected [iommu] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: security level set to 'none'
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [60201c9e-0ea8-domain0                    ] domain: registered (bootacl: 0/0)
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [60201c9e-0ea8-domain0                    ] bootacl: bootacl not supported, no sync
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [60201c9e-0ea8-domain0                    ] store: storing newly connected domain
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: journal: opened for '60201c9e-0ea8'; size: 0 bytes
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: udev: could not create device: failed to get sysfs attr: device
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/901fdff4_0845_8680_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/b0487488_6ef6_8680_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/1050819f_020c_8680_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/70a70644_67b0_8680_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/60201c9e_0ea8_8680_ffff_ffffffffffff
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [00e2202d-3182-Thunderbolt Dock G2        ] dbus: exported device at /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/00e2202d_3182...
Jan 28 20:43:41 qdrop-swift5 systemd[1]: Started Thunderbolt system service.
Jan 28 20:45:19 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: power: setting force_power to ON
Jan 28 20:45:59 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [00e2202d-3182-Thunderbolt Dock G2        ] parent is 60201c9e-0ea8...
Jan 28 20:45:59 qdrop-swift5 boltd[781]: [00e2202d-3182-Thunderbolt Dock G2        ] connected: authorized (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.2/domain0/0-0/0-1)
```

Furthermore, the notebook is not charging - even the G2 should support doing so. How can I enforce this?

Note: Secure-Boot is disabled. I have no more settings in BIOS regarding the Thunderbolt security.

Any help is highly appreciated. I can also send you logs if that helps. Just let me know how to get them.

Comment: Ooh, shiny. Your specs show _USB Type-C port supporting: USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps) and Thunderbolt 3` so it _should_ work. I'd try another USB-C cable.

Comment: I don't think the cable is the issue: It works flawlessly when booting with the cable attached.